# Get the list of check items in Select Drobdown Check Box In Blazor with C#

Tags: c#, blazor

In the Blazor project, we needed a DropDownCheckBox for which I created the HTML template from Blazor. and you can see in this picture:
[image]

If an item checked or one of the items is unchecked, the `console.log(this.selectedOptions)` method will be executed and the list of choices will be displayed in the log section of the browser.

```
<div class="information__set toggle_module">
    <div class="information_wrapper form--fields row">
        <div class="col-md-6" style="padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div>

                    <div class="container">
                        <h1>Multiselect-dropdown demo!</h1>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col ">
                                <hr />
                                @if (Items != null)
                                {
                                    <label>Select 2</label>
                                    <select name="field2" id="field2" multiple multiselect-search="true" multiselect-select-all="false" multiselect-max-items="1" onchange="console.log(this.selectedOptions)">
                                        @foreach (var itm in Items)
                                        {
                                            if (!itm.Selected)
                                            {
                                                <option value="@itm.ItemID">@itm.SelItms</option>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                <option selected value="@itm.ItemID">@itm.SelItms</option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                    </select>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <br /><br /><br />
                        <button class="btn btn-light" onclick="field2.innerHTML='<option value=1>New option 1</option><option selected value=2>New option 2</option><option value=3>New option 3</option>';field2.loadOptions()">Load new options</button>

                        <input type="text" id="ttt" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The C# code part in Blazor:

```
@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public List<MultiSelectList> Items { get; set; } = null!;

    MultiSelectList fref = new MultiSelectList();

    string IntSelectedCountryID;

    string IntSelectedCountryIDMain
    {
        get
        {
            return IntSelectedCountryID;
        }
        set
        {
            IntSelectedCountryID = value;
            Console.WriteLine(value.ToString() + "------------------");
        }
    }


    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Items = new List<MultiSelectList>();
        MultiSelectList m;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            m = new MultiSelectList();
            if (i == 3)
            {
                m.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                m.Selected = false;
            }
            m.ItemID = i + 1;
            m.SelItms = "Item " + i.ToString();
            Items.Add(m);
        }
    }



    private void CheckboxChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Value.ToString());
    }

    public class MultiSelectList
    {
        public int ItemID { get; set; }
        public string SelItms { get; set; }
        public Boolean Selected { get; set; }
    }
}
```

How can I transfer the list sent by the `console.log(this.selectedOptions)` method to C# parameters or variables and use it in the program. Thank you for your kindness and attention.
The link of html spurce with java and other files:  https://github.com/admirhodzic/multiselect-dropdown

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using MudBlazor that way you can bind anything you've selected in the `comboBox` for example

```
<MudSelect IconSize='Size.Small'Dense="true" MultiSelection=true @bind-SelectedValues='selectedValues'>
    @for(var i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    <MudSelectItem>item @i</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>

@code
{
private IEnumerable<string> selectedValues {get; set;} = new HashSet<string();
}
```

In your button you can loop the values like `foreach` `selectedValues`

Please see the example on their website

https://mudblazor.com/components/select#variants

Comment: Thanks @Cyrille Con Morales for your reply. Is the Mud component free or does it have to be paid for?

Comment: I add the builder.Services.AddScoped<MudBlazor.Services.IKeyInterceptor>(); inside of startup but I got error: System.ArgumentException: Cannot instantiate implementation type 'MudBlazor.Services.IKeyInterceptor' for service type 'MudBlazor.Services.IKeyInterceptor'.

Comment: Hello, my dear friend, thank you for your reply. But this code that you sent me needs to install a separate component and unfortunately I am not allowed to install other components in this project. Therefore, if you have a solution that can correct the code I posted, then I will be grateful. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

@onchange="CheckboxChanged">

If you want to manage the selected or unselected list items you have to collect them for example in a List and tracking their modifications.

**UPDATE**
Hi, I do not know what you want but it works for me:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Multiselect-dropdown demo!</h1>
  <div class="row"><div class="col ">
    <label>Select 1</label>
    <select name="field1" id="field1" multiple 
        @onchange="CheckboxChanged"
        multiselect-hide-x="true">
      <option value="1">Audi</option>
      <option selected value="2">BMW</option>
      <option selected value="3">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="4">Volvo</option>
      <option value="5">Lexus</option>
      <option value="6">Tesla</option>
    </select>
  </div></div>
```

```
private void CheckboxChanged(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var listOfSelectedElements= ((IList<string>)e.Value);
}
```

Sorry, If misunderstood again.

Comment: The code you sent is not the answer. The desired method is a method inside the Java file and must be called in another way and the result sent to the C-Sharp parameter.

Comment: Sorry, but where is here any Java files? Your code is wrong and your answer is not kind at all.

Comment: Hi @sada you can find total files in https://github.com/admirhodzic/multiselect-dropdown

Comment: Again: 1. Where is Java file? This is C# not Java. 2. console.log(this.selectedOptions) dosen't send any list just write it out of console. 3. You have to manage selection and unselection because the use can change it any time. 4. If someone try to help you do not be so arrogant because you won't get any answers next time.

Comment: my dear friend @sada at first I should say thank you  for you reply. then `onchange="console.log(this.selectedOptions)" ` code is an executable type in HTML and is different from `@onclick` Command inside of Blazor Codes. Before I made this ticket, I almost searched this website and the internet, but most people mistakenly suggested a solution like you and other friends, which was not applicable in my code, and that's why I had to make a ticket, and unfortunately the answer Your submission was not executed. In fact, it did not meet my needs. Part 2-1

Comment: Part 2-2 @sada You could understand this with a little care and without anger. But I don't know why you asked me to review and send the Java code several times. While I had even sent the link to the original HTML project for you to see, dear friend. I hope you are successful and if you have a solution for this issue, I would be happy if you could guide me with your experience.

Comment: @sada thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for when searching for "Get the list of check items in Select Drobdown Check Box In Blazor with C#"

Answer (score -2):

Ok, this is what you are doing:

When the user selects a new option you write in the console the list. It is very, very simple your problem.

you need to declare a list in the code section, then when onclick event clicks, instead of writing the list through the console, you call another method something like `onchange="@MyMethod(this.selectedOptions)"`

then

```
@code{
.....
void MyMethod(...){
myList = myparameter;
}
...}
```

myList is the list you have defined, you need the @ to say that this is c# code

Comment: Thanks @Iria for sending the code. But unfortunately the code you sent did not work and the correct code was not sent. This command is from the series of HTML commands that I want to run in Blazor. But apparently you have confused it with the click command in Blazer itself. thank you.